# How do I convert a TypeScript class method to a pure function that doesn't write to the class state within the function?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

Working my way back towards functional programming in Node after entering the world of TypeScript and Angular object oriented tendencies for a while, I'm trying to make my class methods "pure". From what I understand, I can't change a parameter in a method and I can't write to a private class variable directly within the method. How would I convert `processNewImageStack` into a pure function? (full [code-in-progress here](https://github.com/owntheweb/twin-tiger-security-camera/blob/master/camera/motion-capturer/src/motion-capturer.ts))

```
export class MotionCapturer {
  // Stack images ready for upload as able.
  private uploadImageStack = new FileStack();
  private uploadImageBusy: false;

  // ...

  /**
    * Process the new cam image stack one item at a time as available.
    */
  private processNewImageStack = async (): Promise<void> => {
    if (this.newImageBusy === false && this.newImageStack.length > 0) {
      // Don't process other stack items until this one is finished.
      this.newImageBusy = true;

      // Take the top/last item in the stack.
      const stackImage = this.newImageStack.pop();

      try {
        // Get the image thumbnail for comparison with previous thumbnail when detecting motion
        const thumbPath = await this.extractThumbnailAsFile(stackImage, this.options.tempImageDirectory);
        const newThumb = await this.loadThumbnail(thumbPath);

        // Detect motion.
        const motionDetected = this.detectMotion(newThumb, this.previousThumb, this.motionHotspots, this.options.motionSensitivity);

        // Upload image if motion was detected.
        if (motionDetected) {
          const movedImage = await this.moveFile(stackImage, 
          this.options.readyImageDirectory);
          this.previousThumb = newThumb; // also setting directly hmm
          this.uploadImageStack.push(movedImage);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('processNewImageStack error', err);
      }

      // All done, open for next item in the stack
      this.newImageBusy = false;
    }
    return;
  }

  private extractThumbnailAsFile = (imagePath: string, tempImageDir: string): Promise<string> => {
    // ...
  }

  private loadThumbnail = async (thumbImagePath: string): Promise<Jimp> => {
    // ...
  };

  private detectMotion = (newThumb: Jimp, prevThumb: Jimp, hotspots: HotspotBoundingBox[], motionSensitivity: number): boolean => {
    // ...
  };

  private moveFile = (filePath: string, destinationDir: string): Promise<string> => {
    // ...
  }

  public init = (): void => {
    setInterval(() => this.processNewImageStack, 500);
  }
}
```

Currently it's checking `this.newImageBusy` and `this.newImageStack.length`, which I'm guessing I should set as parameters? Also, it's setting `this.newImageBusy` outside the scope of the method. I should call a function that sets it instead of setting, correct?

Also, I'm aware that classes are outside of Functional Programming it seems. I can address that separately.

Comment: classes _can_ be used as part of FP (and I don't mean like Haskell's type-classes, I mean C#/Java-style `class`). You just need to be careful about what state is mutable.

Comment: I took out several await calls for this example. I'll fill it in momentarily. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: It's difficult (if not impossible) to answer your question without knowing _exactly_ what `processNewImageStack` is meant to do. What is `FileStack` and why must these images be processed serially instead of concurrently? (concurrent execution is independent of asynchrony).

Comment: As mentioned in the post, full code is available [here](https://github.com/owntheweb/twin-tiger-security-camera/blob/master/motion-capturer/src/motion-capturer.ts). I'll add more code here however to fill in context. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Dai The question has been updated. I can add ALL code if needed, however didn't want to overload the question too much.

Comment: There's too many inherent IO effects in that method, with (apparently) networking, file system accesses, and asynchrony. You cannot make this method pure. If you are really determined, you need to find a way to explicitly represent effects as data (there are libraries to do that but no standard one we could recommend). Once you have chosen a particular style, we can you help you make that work.

Comment: Thank you for the good notes @Bergi. I'll dig into this further.

Comment: (Notice that deciding to keep inherently stateful things in imperative style is a valid and common approach too…)

Comment: Also helpful and a relief as I address these things. Thank you!

Comment: Imagine converting a mountain bike to a racing machine (or the other way around). Do you think the result would be satisfying? It would be most likely more satisfying when you start to construct a racing machine from scratch. Therefore my advice would be to try a clean slate and learn FP from scratch without distracting idioms from another paradigm.

Comment: I agree with the comments. If someone wants to provide feedback in answer form, I'll be happy to award the points.